# How to use a FileWriter to write to a File?

Tags: java

I have written a program that reads 150 files froma folder and it creates a new folder and creates those 150 files and writes contents to it..

heres my code:

```
package TestPackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeSorting {
    // path till 'employee files' folder.
    File folder = new File("D:\\Arthi iyer\\employee files");

    // listFiles() : list all the files in a folder.
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    ArrayList<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    String[] split_input = null;

    public void sortFiles() throws IOException {

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            split_input = input.split("=");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(split_input[1]);

            String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
            split_input = input1.split("=");
            String name = split_input[1];

            String input2 = scanner.nextLine();
            split_input = input2.split("=");
            int age = Integer.parseInt(split_input[1]);

            emp.add(new Employee(id, name, age));

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            File idFile = new File("D:\\Arthi iyer\\employee id" + "\\" + id
                    + ".txt");
            FileWriter idcopy = new FileWriter(idFile);

            int idbuffersize1;
            char[] a = new char[1000];

            while ((idbuffersize1 = br.read(a)) > 0) {

                idcopy.write(a, 0, idbuffersize1);

            }

        }// for ends
    }// method ends

    public void sortByID() {

        System.out.println("----Sort By Employee Id----");
        Collections.sort(emp, new EmployeeSortById());
        printEmployees(emp);
    }

    // print employee
    public void printEmployees(ArrayList<Employee> emp) {
        for (Employee e : emp) {

            System.out.println("Id->" + e.getEmp_id() + " " + " Name-> "
                    + e.getEmp_name() + "  " + "age-> " + e.getAge());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File id_folder = new File("D:\\Arthi iyer\\employee id");
        id_folder.mkdir(); // mkdir() for making directory.

        EmployeeSorting sort = new EmployeeSorting();
        sort.sortFiles();
        // sort.sortByID();

    }

}
```

my problem is files are being created to folder but contents are not being written..please guide me

Comment: Did you try to do this for *one* file? Does it work?

Comment: no but when i tried to write contents using for loop in console that were getting printed but not getting written to file..is there any proble with my writer?

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing the writer, so all the data is probably just staying in the internal buffer.

Ideally, use a try-with-resources statement, or close it in a `finally` block.

```
int idbuffersize1;
char[] a = new char[1000];
FileWriter idcopy = new FileWriter(idFile);
try {  
    while ((idbuffersize1 = br.read(a)) > 0) {
        idcopy.write(a, 0, idbuffersize1);
    }
} finally {
    idcopy.close();
}
```

As an aside, I personally don't like `FileWriter`, as it always uses the system default encoding, rather than allowing you to specify an encoding. I prefer using a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not flush or close the file, thus, the content could not be written to the file.

In addition, I strongly recommend you using `BufferedWriter` or `PrintWriter` to write normal text.